# Why SBT gives me "not found: object akka" with "import akka._"?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've the following `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "Stocks"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"   % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"   % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote"  % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-agent"   % "2.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.3" % "test"
)
```

When I `import akka._` in a `.scala` file I'm getting the error:

```
[error] /home.......stocks/src/main/scala/main.scala:3: not found: object akka
[error] import akka._
```

Why?

Comment: I just tried this, and it works. Are you launching `sbt` from the right directory (the root of the project, which should be where the `build.sbt` file is)?

Comment: Sir, your karma just improved considerably, somewhere I must have missed that the build.sbt file should be in the top and not anywhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory structure needs to look like this:

```
.
├── build.sbt
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── main.scala
```

And you have to launch `sbt` from the project's root directory (where the `build.sbt` file is).

---

Side note: If were to use a Scala build configuration instead of `build.sbt`, that would go in the `project` directory instead.

```
.
├── project
│   └── Build.scala
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── main.scala
```

Comment: What does this mean exactly. I'm having the same exact problem right now. Does the location of my build.sbt matter?